Install executables as well libraries with setuptools
I have a C++ code that generates a python expansion, through setuptools.Extension.
In the setup.py file , I define a build_ext, and relies upon CMake to build the extension :
class BuildCMakeExtension(build_ext.build_ext):
  """Our custom build_ext command.

  Uses CMake to build extensions instead of a bare compiler (e.g. gcc, clang).
  """

  def run(self):
    self._check_build_environment()
    for ext in self.extensions:
      self.build_extension(ext)

  def _check_build_environment(self):
    ...

  def build_extension(self, ext):
    extension_dir = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))
    build_cfg = 'Debug' if self.debug else 'Release'
    cmake_args = [
        ...
    ]
    ...
    os.makedirs(self.build_temp, exist_ok=True)
    subprocess.check_call(
        ['cmake', ext.source_dir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
    subprocess.check_call(
        ['cmake', '--build', '.', f'-j{os.cpu_count()}', '--config', build_cfg],
        cwd=self.build_temp)

    # Force output to <extension_dir>/. Amends CMake multigenerator output paths
    # on Windows and avoids Debug/ and Release/ subdirs, which is CMake default.
    ct_dir = os.path.join(extension_dir, 'cytosim')  # pylint:disable=unreachable
    for cfg in ('Release', 'Debug'):
      cfg_dir = os.path.join(extension_dir, cfg)
      if os.path.isdir(cfg_dir):
        for f in os.listdir(cfg_dir):
          shutil.move(os.path.join(cfg_dir, f), ct_dir)

In the CMakeLists of the project, I add the module through pybind11_add_module(cytosim  ${PYCY_SOURCES}) and set_target_properties(cytosim PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PY_LIBRARY_NAME}")
This works well somehow (no idea how tbh) and I happily find my cytosim.xxxxx.so file in the right place site_packages/cytosim once the build is done.
However, the compilation also creates an executable, via add_executable(${SIM_TARGET} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/sim/sim.cc") ; however it does not go in site_packages.
How can I do to get it there ?

Full Project is here : https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/tree/pybind?ref_type=heads

I did not find a clean solution, but I did find a working solution based off : Distributing a binary utility in setuptools
We cannot list the executable as a script because a script needs to be text. We cannot put the executable as package data, because we want the freshly compiled executable (rather than a stale executable compiled possibly for a different platform...).
The solution is indeed to distribute a script that is just a wrapper around the compiled executable, and to move the compiled executable to the extension directory during the build.
First we need in setup to have the foowrapper package declared, and the foo script, that will be a wrapper around the executable :
setup(
  ...
  packages=['foowrapper'],
  scripts=['foowrapper/foo']
  ...
)

In my case I move the executable to the foowrapper folder during the build extension function :
def build_extension(self, ext):
    extension_dir = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))
    ...
    parent = pathlib.Path(extension_dir).parent.absolute()
    for p in os.listdir(parent):
        pp = os.path.join(parent, p)
        if os.path.isdir(pp) and  p.startswith("temp."):
                       for f in os.listdir(pp):
                ff = os.path.join(pp, f)
                if os.access(ff, os.X_OK):
                    if f=="foo":
                        pybin = os.path.join(extension_dir, "foowrapper")
                        if not os.path.isdir(pybin):
                            os.mkdir(pybin)
                        shutil.move(ff, os.path.join(pybin, "wrapped_foo"))


Here I move the executable "foo" to the folder "foowrapper", and I rename it "wrapped_foo" ; while "foo" will be a wrapper script, that calls "wrapped_foo" :
#!python
import foowrapper as fw
import os,sys
import subprocess

""" A wrapper for foo """ 

path = os.path.dirname(fw.__file__)
exe = os.path.join(path, "wrapped_foo") 
subprocess.call([exe] + sys.argv[1:])

